# Concatenation operation on set with String elements with Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, generics, swift5, xcode12

What I want is a `+` operation on `Set<String>`. It should calculate a new set with string concatenation of each individual element on the left with the elements of the set on the right.

**Example**: the result of `["a","b","c"] +  ["1","2"] + ["x","y"]` is a new set with elements: `["c1x", "b2x", "c2x", "c2y", "b1y", "b2y", "a1x", "b1x", "a1y", "a2x", "a2y", "c1y"]`.

I'm using this code now:

```
protocol ConcatType {
    static func + (lhs : Self, rhs : Self) -> Self
}

extension String : ConcatType {

}

extension Set where Element : ConcatType {
    static func + (lhs: Set<Element>, rhs: Set<Element>) -> Set<Element> {
        var res : Set<Element> = Set<Element>()
        for ell in lhs {
            for elr in rhs {
                res = res.union([ell + elr])
            }
        }
        return res
    }
}

let set1 : Set<String> = ["a","b","c"]
let set2 : Set<String> = ["1","2"]

var set3 = set1+set2

print(set3)
```

Does work as expected :) the result is `["c1", "b1", "c2", "a1", "b2", "a2"]`. But i wonder why i need the "empty" extension here. Without the extension the compiler has trouble with type interfering:

```
extension String : ConcatType {

}
```

I thought about whether there is a better definition of `static func +` in `protocol ConcatType` that makes the extension obsolete.

What do you think about my solution, is it good reasonable Swift code?

Comment: You use the protocol as a requirement so that is why it is needed, another option is to drop the protocol and change the requirement to that element must be a String

Comment: There is not “implicit protocol conformance” in Swift. `String` has a `+` operator matching the requirement of your protocol. That does not mean that it *conforms* to the protocol unless you explicitly say so.

Comment: `extension Set where Element == String`

Comment: If the problem is solved, please answer the question or delete the question.